# Can you focus a child window using a keyboard when it is not focussed?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to focus an application's child window using only key presses?

For example, open a text file in Notepad then press ctrl+F to open the Find dialogue box.
Press either win+D or win+M to minimise Notepad.
Finally use alt+tab to refocus Notepad.

The main window is focussed, not the Find dialogue box.

Is there any standard way in Windows to move focus back to the Find dialogue box, by pressing keys?

Yes I am aware that in this specific example I could press ctrl+F again, but I am looking for a general keyboard method that would also work for child windows that cannot be focussed by pressing some application-specific keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually switch between child-windows using Ctrl+Tab (You can also use Ctrl+F4 to close them).